# Limit Array to multiple specific data types

Tags: arrays, powershell, class

I am working on refactoring a tool to OOP in PS5.

I have a number of classes. Sets can contain other Sets as well as Packages. Packages can contain other Packages and Tasks. And Tasks can contain other Tasks. For example...

```
Set1
   Package1.1
      Task1.1
Set2
   Package2.1
      Task2.1
   Set2A
      Package2A
         Task2A.1
         Task2A.2
   Package2.2
      Task2.2
Set3
   Package3.1
      Task3.1
         Task3.1A
```

I plan to have Set, Package and Task classes, but there are a number of different Tasks with some common features and some unique, so I will have a base Task class that is then extended by the various final task classes.
My question relates to the data structure to contain the nested objects. If each class could only contain the next deeper type everything would be easy; the variable to hold the Packages in a Set could be an array of Packages, i.e. `[Package[]]$Contents`.
I could make it super flexible and just do an array; `[Array]$Contents`, but that allows for invalid items like strings and such.
Alternatively I could have some sort of Root class, with Sets, Packages and Tasks all extended that, and final Tasks then extending Tasks, and use`[Root[]]$Contents` or some such. But that might not be possible and it would still allow for adding a Task to a Set, since a final Task class would ultimately be extending from Root. 
So, the question becomes, can you define an array that accepts multiple possible types but is still limited, something like `[Set/Package[]]$Contents`? Or is there perhaps a totally different way to define a variable that limits the valid members? An Enum seems to have potential, but it seems like they are limited to strings as I tried

```
enum AllowedTypes {
    [Array]
    [Strings]
}
```

and that in no good.
Or am I best of just using an Array and validating what I am adding in the Add method of each Class? I can see a possible solution there where I have overloaded Add methods in the Set class, one that takes a Set, one that takes a Package, and one that takes a generic object and throws an error to log. Assuming that the more specific overload method takes priority rather than everything going to the generic method since it's technically valid. Or perhaps that generic method won't even work since the collection of overloaded Add methods technically can't collapse to one valid choice because a Set is both a [Set] and a [PSObject] I guess.

Comment: `class MyCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Object] { [Type[]]$ValidTypes; MyCollection([Type[]]$ValidTypes) { $this.ValidTypes = $ValidTypes } InsertItem([int]$Index, [Object]$Item) { if($this.ValidTypes | ? { $Item -is $_ }) { ([System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Object]]$this).InsertItem($Index, $Item) } else { throw 'Wrong type' } } SetItem([int]$Index, [Object]$Item) { if($this.ValidTypes | ? { $Item -is $_ }) { ([System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Object]]$this).SetItem($Index, $Item) } else { throw 'Wrong type' } } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as countless times before, has provided an excellent (uncommented) solution in a comment on the question, without coming back to post that solution as an *answer*.

Given the limits of code formatting in comments, it's worth presenting the solution in a more readable format; additionally, it has been streamlined, modularized, extended, and commented:

In short: **a PowerShell [*custom class* (PSv5+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes) is used to *subclass* standard type [`[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[object]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1) in order to limit adding elements to a list of permitted types passed to the constructor**.

```bsh
class MyCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[object] { 

  # The types an instance of this collection
  # is permitted to store instance of, initialized via the constructor.
  [Type[]] $permittedTypes

  # The only constructor, to which the permitted types must be passed.
  MyCollection([Type[]] $permittedTypes) { $this.permittedTypes = $permittedTypes } 

  # Helper method to determine if a given object is of a permitted type.
  [bool] IsOfPermittedType([object] $item) {
    return $this.permittedTypes.Where({ $item -is $_ }, 'First')
  }

  # Hidden helper method for ensuring that an item about to be inserted / added
  # / set is of a permissible type; throws an exception, if not.
  hidden AssertIsOfPermittedType([object] $item) {
    if (-not $this.IsOfPermittedType($item)) {
      Throw "Type not permitted: $($item.GetType().FullName)"
    }
  }

  # Override the base class' .InsertItem() method to add type checking.
  # Since the original method is protected, we mark it as hidden.
  # Note that the .Add() and .Insert() methods don't need overriding, because they
  # are implemented via this method.
  hidden InsertItem([int] $index, [object] $item) {
    $this.AssertIsOfPermittedType($item)
    ([System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[object]] $this).InsertItem($index, $item) 
  } 

  # Override the base class' SetItem() method to add type checking.
  # Since the original method is protected, we mark it as hidden.
  # This method is implicitly called when indexing ([...]) is used.
  hidden SetItem([int] $index, [object] $item) {
    $this.AssertIsOfPermittedType($item)
    ([System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[object]] $this).SetItem($index, $item) 
  } 

  # Note: Since the *removal* methods (.Remove(), .RemoveAt()) 
  #       need to type checking, there is no need to override them.

}
```

With the above class defined, here's sample code that exercises it:

```bsh
# Create an instance of the custom collection type, passing integers and strings
# as the only permitted types.
# Note the (...) around the type arguments, because they must be passed
# as a *single argument* that is an *array*.
# Without the inner (...) PowerShell would try to pass them as *individual arguments*.
$myColl = [MyCollection]::new(([int], [string]))

# OK, add an [int]
# .Add() implicitly calls the overridden .InsertItem() method.
$myColl.Add(1) 

$myColl.Add('hi') # OK, add a [string]

# OK, override the 1st element with a different [int]
# (though a [string] would work too).
# This implicitly calls the overridden .SetItem() method.
$myColl[0] = 2 

# OK - insert a [string] item at index 0
$myColl.Insert(0, 'first')

# $myColl now contains: 'first', 2, 'hi'

# Try to add an impermissible type:
$myColl.Add([long] 42)
# -> Statement-terminating error:
# 'Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Type not permitted: System.Int64"'
```

Comment: Thanks, @PetSerAl - answer updated; I've also marked the overridden method as `hidden` so as not to tempt users to call them directly (and I've also slightly refactored the type-checking code).